# Make a POST call every 10 seconds for an infinite time?

Tags: android, post, service, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

How can I make a certain function execute after every 10 seconds for an infinite time?

**What I have done till now:** I am getting the location values of the user from the App and storing them on the server. I am using a service, so that, the code keeps running for an infinite time, I am using a Broadcast receiver, so that, if the phone is booted, the service should start again and starts sending me the location.

**The issue** Everything works perfectly fine for about first 10-15 minutes, but, after this, the service gets stopped by itself. Also, when the user signs up for the App, authorized tokens are generated. These tokens are also sent in the *POST* call as one of the parameters, for security purposes. Even these tokens are lost, despite working perfectly fine for the initial 10 minutes. I am storing these tokens in SharedPreferences. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

**Code for SharedPreferences**

```
Log.i("onCreate", "onCreate");
Log.i("atoken value", ConfirmToken.avalue);
Log.i("utoken value", ConfirmToken.uvalue);
atoken = ConfirmToken.avalue;
utoken = ConfirmToken.uvalue;
Log.i("atoken value", atoken);
Log.i("utoken value", utoken);
Log.i("Starting SharedPref", "Starting SharedPref");
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("atoken", atoken);
editor.putString("utoken", utoken);
editor.commit();
if (settings.contains("atoken")) { 
    atoken = settings.getString("atoken", "nulll");
    Log.i("Inside SharedPref", atoken);
}

if(settings.contains("utoken")) {
    utoken = settings.getString("utoken", "nulll");
    Log.i("Inside Sharedprefs", utoken);
}
//Calling UpdateData here so that values of lat, lng get updated, before they are used by MyService.java
UpdateData();
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Now, the update data function simple makes a POST call, using these tokens and Location values as parameters.

Comment: how tokens are lost when you said you are saving them in preferences ? They could have been overwritten ? You must check why and where ?

Comment: Initially the tokens are working fine, but, after about sometime, what I am getting is a null value.

Comment: are you resetting the tokens in preferences anywhere ?

Comment: Please refer the code, I have just edited the question. Do let me know in case you need any further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I run a task every few seconds. Note that it runs in another thread, so accessing UI elements needs `runOnUiThread` call, but since you are in a service, you will not have any issues with that.

```
private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor taskExecutor;

private void stopTimerTask() {
        if (taskExecutor != null)
            taskExecutor.shutdownNow();
        // keep one task at any given time
        taskExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    }

    private void startTimerTask() {
        stopTimerTask();
        taskExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Timer_Tick, TIMER_INITIAL_DELAY, TIMER_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Log.d("Pool", "Timer Task Running");
    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something
        }
    };
```

You should however be aware that Android OS may terminate your service at any time when running low on resources or it feels like the service is doing too much work. You should start focusing on how to restore it's state, just like every one else does.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is the easiest way. 
Also remember if you are making a network call, make an asynchronous request so that your app doesn't stop working while your app waits for the response.

```
for(long startTime = new Date().getTime();new Date().getTime() - startTime ==10000; startTime++)
{ /*your code goes here*/ };
```

No matter what you do, if the system is low on resources, it will terminate your app.Please let me know weather this works for you or not :)